# Xamarin.Forms - Looking for a Popover

Tags: xaml, user-interface, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm working in a Xamarin.Forms project (iOS & Android) that needs something similar to the [Bootstrap Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers). I didn't find something similar in the docs.

Q:

Does anyone know a Nuget Package or something similar that in order to include that UI component to a Xamarin.Forms project?

PS: Yes, I tried searching in Google and I could not found a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Rg.Popup](https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup) is a good solution...

```
// Use these methods in PopupNavigation globally or Navigation in your pages

// Open new PopupPage
Task PushAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.PushPopupAsync

// Hide last PopupPage
Task PopAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopPopupAsync

// Hide all PopupPage with animations
Task PopAllAsync(bool animate = true) // Navigation.PopAllPopupAsync

// Remove one popup page in stack
Task RemovePageAsync(PopupPage page, bool animate = true) // Navigation.RemovePopupPageAsync
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using the Rg.Popup package and it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try out [**CPOP**](https://github.com/fedec93/CPop). It's a popup plugin for **Xamarin.Forms (iOS, Android, UWP)**. It's not the prettiest of the popups, but you can modify the colors. (Also, I think this is the only popup plugin available out there)

NuGet Package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Calvagna.CPop/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try [SlideOverKit](http://www.xam-consulting.com/slideoverkit-xamarin-forms/), it might do more than you need, but it has a nice range of ways of doing popover type things.